# Multiple Order by (date and time ) not working in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am combining multiple tables, filtering and then ordering by certain format. Every time I try to order by both date and time, it messes up the output.

```
SELECT
     t1.empid,t2.lastName,t2.firstName
    ,t1.date as "OVERBOOKED DATE",t1.sfrom,t1.dept as "dname"
    ,t3.manager as "MANAGER" 
from schedule_2 as t1 
INNER JOIN employees_2 as t2 ON t1.empid = t2.empid 
INNER JOIN dept_heads as t3 ON t1.dept = t3.Dept_name 
JOIN  ( SELECT empid,date from schedule_2 
GROUP BY empid,date 
having count(empid)>1
) inr  on inr.empid=t1.empid and inr.date=t1.date 
ORDER BY empid ASC, "OVERBOOKED DATE"  ASC, sfrom ASC;
```

Im attaching the snippet of the output and the snippet of expected output. Im new to this, so would appreciate any help!

[[image: Current Output]

[[image: Expected Output]

Comment: SQL does not need to be in a single unbroken line. Please in future format the query to avoid left/right scrolling

Comment: what is the data type of the column `sFrom`? it looks like a varchar?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the values in your `sfrom` column are not valid inputs to the `DATE` function (as you are using it in your "Current Output" query). You need to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert them to a valid value for ordering i.e. replace `sfrom` (or `DATE(sfrom)`) in your `ORDER BY` clause with

```
ORDER BY empid ASC, "OVERBOOKED DATE"  ASC, STR_TO_DATE(sfrom, '%h%p') ASC
```

**Edit**

As has been pointed out by @TimBiegeleisen, `"OVERBOOKED DATE"` is just a string literal and is not valid to sort by, either the raw column name (`t1.date`), a regular name alias (`OVERBOOKED_DATE`) or the alias name in backticks should be used e.g.

```
ORDER BY empid ASC, `OVERBOOKED DATE`  ASC, STR_TO_DATE(sfrom, '%h%p') ASC
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are mistaken (for once!). From the manual: `STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I *did* test it on my local MySQL server (5.6) and phpMyAdmin; if I could paste an image in a comment I could show you...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it works on rextester too: https://rextester.com/KXXXR59213

Comment: Your right...my alias name in the demo had a problem.  This should work +1.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, makes the "overbooked date" out of order. Instead making on the sfrom in order.

Comment: Got this to work with use from the answer below. But how would I change the date format from m/d/y to m-d-y ?

Comment: @RaghavGupta you should be able to use `DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS OVERBOOKED_DATE`

Answer (score 0):

You are storing date and time separately, which isn't usually a good idea, because it often leads to problems exactly like the one you are facing now.  Given that the hour portion of your time string is fixed width, and that `AM/PM` sort correctly in ascending order, we can try the following:

```
ORDER BY
    empid,
    OVERBOOKED_DATE,    -- DON'T use aliases with spaces, if you plan to order by them
    RIGHT(sfrom, 2),
    LEFT(sfrom, 2);
```

Note: Doing `ORDER BY "OVERBOOKED DATE"` appears to be ordering by a string literal, which is really no ordering at all.  Instead, use the following alias:

```
OVERBOOKED_DATE
```

And then order by this single term alias.

Comment: this then usorts the Overbooked date

Comment: @RaghavGupta I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Using your way, the overbooked dates, don't get ordered, but instead all sfrom get ordered together

Comment: @RaghavGupta Read my updated answer.  Avoid using aliases with whitespace.  Just use `OVERBOOKED_DATE`, and then order by exactly this.